# fixing the error in query codeigniter model syntax error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model

Why is this i am getting error in my Model in codeigniter where it says :

```
A Database Error Occured
Error Number: 1064 
You have error in your SQL syntax;
```

when i tried run it in mysql it works fine. But when i put it in the model of my CI it gives me Error Number: 1064

Here is my full model code:

```
public function checkupID() {
        $query = $this->db->query(' SELECT check_up_id FROM tbl_check_up JOIN (SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL)) AS max_right FROM tbl_check_up) AS x
                    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) = max_right ');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

my table structure

```
+-------------+----------+---------+--------+
|  Field      |  Type    |  NULL   | Key    |
+-------------+----------+---------+--------+
| check_up_id | varchar  |  NO     | PRI    |
+-------------+----------+---------+--------+
| note        | varchar  |  YES    |        |
+-------------+----------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you please add `x.max_right` at the end instead of `max_right`

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya THANK YOU for your reply sir.. . Why is it , that it appears error in codeigniter while in mysql works fine?

Comment: First let me know it works for you or not in CI.?

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya thanks for fast reply sir. In CI it doesn't work and alerting an error of A Database Error Occured, it says check the syntax. but in mysql . it works fine.

Comment: Let me gives you proper solution for this, Can you share your table schema for `tbl_check_up`?

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya hello sir, .. i drawed a tbl structure for my tbl_check_up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147675/discussion-between-shyam-shingadiya-and-jc-john).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find my answer describe below. You can create stored procedure in mysql like give below.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getCheckUpId`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getCheckUpId`()
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        t1.check_up_id 
    FROM tbl_check_up t1 
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.check_up_id, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL)) AS max_right FROM tbl_check_up t2) AS x ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.check_up_id, '-', -1) = x.max_right;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now in your model you can create like described below.

```
public function checkupID() {
    $query = $this->db->query('call getCheckUpId()');
    return $query->row();
}
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know if it not works.

Comment: @JcJohn : Glad to help you out from this hurdle,

Comment: Why you need to write procedure? you can simple put Douable Quations to the query.   $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT check_up_id FROM tbl_check_up JOIN (SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL)) AS max_right FROM tbl_check_up) AS x
                    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(check_up_id, '-', -1) = max_right ");

Comment: @438sunil : Do you think with `double quotes` `(")` this can be resolved..?